# Stopping Thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

if i have got such java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for(int i = 0;i<100;i++)
    {
        Future<?> f = ThreadPoolManager.getInstance().schedule(new START(), 500);
        f.cancel(true);
    }
}
private class START implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println(1);
    }
}
```

And run it in debug, i can see that all of those threads(after cancel) are still running, so are they taking my memory too? And if yes, how can i destroy those Threads completely?

Comment: Are you sure you want to destroy them?

Comment: If they are not going to be used anymore, why not? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cancel(true)` calls `interrupt()` on your thread, nothing more. So, you need to handle it properly in your `run()` method. For your simple case your threads will finish their execution and their objects will be cleared by GC.

Comment: but even if i will not cancel(true) those threads and let them print "1", in debug they will still be Running.

Comment: Specification says that thread dies after returning from run, so you should not aware of it. Probably it is only for debug mode of your IDE their are waiting for root thread to stop.

Comment: aha, so thats cool, i was afraid that it would drain my whole memory after a while if i would constantly add threads. Thx a lot :)